# Given groups=1, weight of size [16, 6, 3, 3], expected input[1, 16, 32, 32] to have 6 channels, but got 16 channels instead

Tags: python, runtime

I tried to run the following program for stereo image super-resolution in Pytorch. I am new to PyTorch and I am not getting what's wrong with the code. I tried reshaping the images but no help. I am running this code with Cuda. I also tried to reshape convolution layer, but error is still occuring

This is the code

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import math
from torch.quantization import QuantStub, DeQuantStub


class ClippedReLU(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ClippedReLU, self).__init__()
    
    def forward(self, x):
        return x.clamp(min=0., max=1.)
    
class ConvRelu(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, bias=True):
        super(ConvRelu, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, padding=(kernel_size//2), bias=bias)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        return x

class Gblock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, groups):
        super(Gblock, self).__init__()
        self.conv0 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, groups=groups)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU(inplace=True)
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(out_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1, padding=0)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv0(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.conv1(x)
        return x

class XLSR_stereo(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, SR_rate):
        super(XLSR_stereo, self).__init__()

        self.conv0_0 = ConvRelu(in_channels=6, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv0_1 = ConvRelu(in_channels=6, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv0_2 = ConvRelu(in_channels=6, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv0_3 = ConvRelu(in_channels=6, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3)

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=6, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=32, kernel_size=1, padding=0)
        self.conv3 = ConvRelu(in_channels=48, out_channels=32, kernel_size=1)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=3 * SR_rate ** 2, kernel_size=3, padding=1)

        self.Gblocks = nn.Sequential(Gblock(32, 32, 4), Gblock(32, 32, 4), Gblock(32, 32, 4))
        self.depth2space = nn.PixelShuffle(SR_rate)
        self.clippedReLU = ClippedReLU()
        
        # init weights
        for m in self.modules():
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                # nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight.data, mode='fan_out', nonlinearity='relu')
                _, fan_out = torch.nn.init._calculate_fan_in_and_fan_out(m.weight.data)
                std = math.sqrt(2/fan_out*0.1)
                torch.nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, mean=0, std=std)
                if m.bias is not None:
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0.01)

    def forward(self, left_image, right_image):
        input_tensor = torch.cat((left_image, right_image), dim=1)
        x = self.conv1(input_tensor)

        res_conv0_0 = self.conv0_0(x)
        res_conv0_1 = self.conv0_1(x)
        res_conv0_2 = self.conv0_2(x)
        res_conv0_3 = self.conv0_3(x)
        res = torch.cat((res_conv0_0, res_conv0_1, res_conv0_2, res_conv0_3), dim=1)

        res = self.conv2(res)
        res = self.Gblocks(res)

        res_conv1 = self.conv1(x)
        res = torch.cat((res, res_conv1), dim=1)

        res = self.conv3(res)
        res = self.conv4(res)
        res = self.clippedReLU(res)

        res = self.depth2space(res)

        return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    device = 'cuda:0'  # Change to 'cpu' if you don't have a GPU
    model = XLSR_stereo(3).to(device)
    model.eval()

    # Create random left and right low-resolution stereo images (batch size = 1)
    left_image = torch.randn(1, 3, 32, 32).to(device)
    right_image = torch.randn(1, 3, 32, 32).to(device)

    # Forward pass through the network
    xx = model(left_image, right_image)
    pred = model(xx)

    batch_size, num_channels, height, width = pred.shape
    num_channels_low_res = num_channels // 2

    HR_pred_l = pred[:, :num_channels_low_res, :, :]
    HR_pred_r = pred[:, num_channels_low_res:, :, :]

    print("Left output shape:", HR_pred_l.shape)
    print("Right output shape:", HR_pred_r.shape)
```

This is the error occured

**RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [16, 6, 3, 3], expected input[1, 16, 32, 32] to have 6 channels, but got 16 channels instead**

I tried to change the channel numbers and rewrite input tensors even then same error is occuring.